# Ruby each_with_index can it act like find_each and get groups of objects so as to release memory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
hash = Hash.new
%w(cat dog wombat).each_with_index {|item, index|
  hash[item] = index
}
hash   #=> {"cat"=>0, "dog"=>1, "wombat"=>2}
```

Example from RubyDoc

I have to iterate over a collection of 100k objects. Usually I would do a find_each but in this case I need the index as well. I can make my own index but I was wondering if there is a rubyism for this case.

I would like something like collection.find_each_with_index

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14528560/convert-an-array-to-hash-where-keys-are-the-indices) then add `.invert` to the end of it in order to swap keys and values in the resultant hash.  Nice idiomatic ruby.

Answer (score 0):

Not pure Ruby but perhaps helpful for those who come here and DO want to answer this question within a Rails framework.

https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.1.0/classes/ActiveRecord/Batches.html#method-i-find_each

```
Person.find_each.with_index do |person, index|
  person.award_trophy(index + 1)
end
```