# Return values in array being not nil + index position

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

```
array = [nil, 3, nil, nil]
```

To return values that are not `nil` I use `array.select {|a| a.present?}`

How would I return the index position as well? E.g by returning a hash table with position as key.

**Update**

Expected output:

```
{1=>3}
```

Comment: Can you post the output you expect for the input array `[nil, 3, nil, nil]` please?

Comment: Updated per your request.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Array#compact](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-compact) to get rid of the nils in a more elegant way:

```
arr = [nil, 3, nil, nil]
arr.compact  # => [3]
```

Then you can use [Array#each_index](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-each_index) to do what you want. For example:

```
Hash[arr.each_index.zip(arr)]
```

Comment: Also `arr.each_index.zip(arr).to_h` on Ruby >= 2, which is more readable

Comment: This will not preserve the element's original position

Comment: That was not a requirement initially, OP updated his question after my answer

Answer (score 2):

I would convert the array into a `position => element` hash first (see [Convert an array to hash, where keys are the indices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14528560/convert-an-array-to-hash-where-keys-are-the-indices)):

```
hash = array.map.with_index { |e, p| [p, e] }.to_h
#=> {0=>nil, 1=>3, 2=>nil, 3=>nil}
```

And filter it afterwards:

```
hash.reject { |k, v| v.nil? }
#=> {1=>3}
```

Comment: Requires Ruby 2.0 though I assume?

Comment: @Numbers you can use `Hash[array.map.with_index { |e, p| [p, e] }]` instead

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
1.9.3-p545 :091 > a = [nil, 3, nil, nil].map.with_index{|p,x| {x => p}}.map{|p| p.delete_if{|k,v| v.nil?}}.reject(&:empty?).inject{}
 => {1=>3} 
1.9.3-p545 :092 >
```