# Convert Array into Hash in Ruby with to_h method

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

I have an array. Despite the fact I can retrieve its index without creating a hash I want to use the array content to create a hash where its index is the value.

```
array = ["Alice", "Bob", "Cliff"]
```

I want my hash to look like:

```
{ "Alice"=>0, "Bob"=>1, "Cliff"=>2 }
```

I appreciate the help.

Comment: [This question and its answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14528560/convert-an-array-to-hash-where-keys-are-the-indices) could be what you're looking for

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [so] is not a code-writing service. You should show in your question a [mcve], the *exact* error message(s) you are getting, representative samples of input and desired output as well as the output you are getting instead of the desired output.

Comment: The to_h method was included beginning in Ruby 2.1. The other example makes no mention of it (possibly because it was answered three years ago).

Answer (score 4):

```
array.each_with_index.to_h
# => {"Alice"=>0, "Bob"=>1, "Cliff"=>2}
```

Answer (score 0):

Map with index solution:

`Hash[ arr.map.with_index { |num, idx| [num, idx] } ]`

Or zip solution:

`Hash[arr.zip(0..arr.size)]`

Comment: There is no `Array#map_with_index`.

Comment: Oops, `map.with_index`. Will edit my post to reflect change, thanks @sawa